# CSS Flicker on Display Block

Tags: css

I have a hidden div which I want displayed on hover of another div. I am getting the desired result, but there is an undesirable flicker. See here http://jsfiddle.net/CL7gj/

HMTL

```
<div id="basin-stlaw"></div>
<div id="stlaw"></div>
```

CSS

```
#basin-stlaw:hover + #stlaw { display:block }

#basin-stlaw {
    width:300px;
    height:250px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(35deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(35deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(35deg);
    left:620px;
    top:75px;
    position:absolute;
    border: thin dotted #39C;
}
#stlaw {
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
    width:900px;
    height:589px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:none;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the selector to include the element `#stlaw` on hover:

[**Updated Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/V6ma4/)

```
#basin-stlaw:hover + #stlaw, #stlaw:hover {
    display:block
}
```

..alternatively, [in supported browsers](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events), you could also use [`pointer-events:none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) for a different result.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/s9A3Q/)

```
#basin-stlaw:hover + #stlaw {
    display:block;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The pointer-events:none gives me what I'm looking for. Can you tell me which browsers do not support it?

Comment: @Greg [**This is a nice reference**](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events) .. if support is an issue, you could also do something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/DxwDj/)

Comment: Josh, thank you again. Your last fiddle works great, but for some reason when I apply it, I'm still getting the flicker as seen here on the Saint Lawrence Bason section http://www.gregtaylordesignstudio.com/Great-Lakes-Project/watershed.html